What is the reference to this hadith?
Can someone give me the reference to the hadith which presents this dua?
'Abdallah ibn 'Abbas reported that the Prophet, peace be upon him, prayed to Allah, "My Lord, help me and do not turn against me. Grant me victory, and do not grant victory over me. Plan on my behalf and do not plan against me. Guide me, and make the guidance easy for me. Grant me victory over those who act wrongfully toward me. O Allah, make me grateful to You, mindful of You, in awe of You, devoted to your obedience,humble, penitent, and ever turning to You in repentance. My Lord, accept my repentance, wash away my sins, answer my supplication, clearly establish my evidence, guide my heart, make my tongue true, and draw out malice from my breast."

The hadith is taken from Tirmidhi: 3551. As a reference, you can check here:
It says:

My Lord, aid me and do not aid against me, and grant me victory and do
not grant victory over me, plot for me and do not plot against me,
guide me and facilitate guidance for me, grant me victory over those
who transgress against me. My Lord, make me ever-grateful to You,
ever-remembering of You, ever-fearful of You, ever-obedient to You,
ever-humble to You, oft-turning and returning to You. My Lord, accept
my repentance, wash my sin, answer my call, make firm my proof, make
firm my tongue, guide my heart, and remove the treachery of my chest.


JazakAllah khair

It is sahih right? I didn't find that information on the hamariweb page (sorry if I am overlooking it).

@Shy, it is authentic as seen https://islamqa.org/hanafi/hadithanswers/155295/a-beautiful-comprehensive-masnun-dua/.
